# Flutter debug console error when installing a package

Tags: flutter, dart

***I get this error when I enter the "flutter pub get" command in the terminal;***

**Error Message:**

```
Because cloud_firestore >=0.13.4 <0.14.0-dev.1 depends on cloud_firestore_web ^0.1.1 which depends on 
firebase ^7.0.0, cloud_firestore >=0.13.4 <0.14.0-dev.1 requires firebase 
^7.0.0.
So, because firebase depends on cloud_firestore ^0.13.7 and firebase is 1.0.0+1, version solving 
failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in firebase...                                
pub get failed (1; So, because firebase depends on cloud_firestore ^0.13.7 and firebase is 1.0.0+1, 
version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the latest version of cloud_firestore_web which is ^1.0.1

```
cloud_firestore_web: ^1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is `firebase_core` you want and not `firestore`? You have firebase 1.0.0+1 which is far from the latest 9.0.0

Comment: I want to set up FireStore